# Monitor a folder for change and save path in db

Tags: python, fastapi, watchdog, python-watchdog

When a file is added to the folder, the path is saved in Db

I found out that there is a package called watchdog but how to integrate it with fast API. is what I can not find yet.

I have modified my Code a bit from the original post so the monitoring will start when fast API starts

```
from fastapi import FastAPI , Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from session import get_session
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
app = FastAPI()

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    db: Session

    def __init__(self, target_folder_path, db: Session = Depends(get_session)):
        super().__init__()
        self.target_folder_path = target_folder_path
        self.db = db

    def on_created(self, event):
        print(f"File {event.src_path} has been created in {self.target_folder_path}")

    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(f"File {event.src_path} has been modified in {self.target_folder_path}")


class WatchdogThread:
    def __init__(self, target_folder_path):
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.target_folder_path = target_folder_path

    def start(self):
        event_handler = MyHandler(self.target_folder_path)
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.target_folder_path, recursive=True)
        print(f"Starting the folder monitoring for {self.target_folder_path}")
        self.observer.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.observer.stop()
        print(f"Stopping the folder monitoring for {self.target_folder_path}")
        self.observer.join()

target_folder_path = "/monitored"

watchdog_thread = WatchdogThread(target_folder_path)

# added this to start the monitoring.
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    watchdog_thread.start()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    watchdog_thread.stop()

def main():
    uvicorn.run("app.main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, access_log=True, reload=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


#Docker-compose 
volumes:
      - ${TARGET_FOLDER_PARENT_PATH}:/monitored:rw
```

Comment: As someone mentioned in a comment to the answer below, there is no need to keep this in your FastAPI application. Have a separate application that is concerned with this part, and let FastAPI be concerned with serving the API endpoint. Also - it'd be helpful if you include what the issue is with your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a FastAPI part, but Uvicorn part.
You can check the souce code here:
https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/supervisors/watchgodreload.py
https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/supervisors/watchfilesreload.py

Comment: Please, clarify your question. Do you want to just add a string-path of a new file to a DB row when file is created? What is FastAPI role you think of?

Comment: Your mistake is that you want to mix this monitoring process with FastAPI server. Just separeti this apps in two diffrent processes: one for FastAPI, another one for file changes monitoring. Both process should get access to DB.